# faster updating of chronograf

Tags: refresh, influxdb, chronograf

I use chronograf influxdb and telegraf for some projects, and I would like to know if it's possible on chronograf to refresh more quickly, since the minimum refresh time is 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Change config here :
https://github.com/influxdata/chronograf/blob/master/ui/src/shared/components/dropdown_auto_refresh/autoRefreshOptions.ts

Instead of installing the pre-compiled version, you need to follow the GitHub instruction to compile the amended source code in order to have your change being effective.

https://github.com/influxdata/chronograf